# Is this a descrete or a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Z\sim exp(1)$. We throw a fair coin independently of $Z$. A random variable $X$ is defined in the following way: if the coin shows "tails", $X=Z$. Otherwise, $X=-Z$.

Is $X$ a descrete or a continuous random variable? And how does it's distribution function look like?

I tend to think it's mixed, but not sure. Any hints of how to deal with such a problem?

Comment: $X$ is continuous because $Z$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X is a mixture of Z and -Z. Since both Z and -Z are continuous, X is also continuous. This particular distribution is called a Laplace distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution

Comment: but in the points where they meet, is it continuous?

Comment: Yes, since exponential distribution is defined and continuous for 0. Please check my edit